# ADO - how to select column from xls file where two or more columns have the same name?

Tags: sql, excel, connection-string, ado

I have an excel file like this:

```
|   |    A   |    B    |    C    |   D    |
| 1 | Name 1 |  Name 2 |  Name 3 | Name 2 |
| 2 |  Data  |  Data   |  Data   | Data   |
| 3 |  Data  |  Data   |  Data   | Data   |
```

As you can see, headers of two columns have the same name - **Name 2**.

My question is, is it possible to tell the ADO engine from which column to select data?

Currently my select looks like this:

```
SELECT [Name 1], [Name 2] FROM [REPORT7_RAW$] WHERE [Name 1] IS NOT NULL
```

and ADO picks up the data from column which is listed under column `B` in excel. In other words it takes the first column which have the given name. Unfortunately I have two columns with the same name and I would like to pull out the data from column `D`. Is it possible?

I could not find any way to select column by its index rather the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to change your connection string so that data header names are not used.  The normal connection string would look something like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

You need to change the last bit, `HDR=YES`, to `HDR=NO`.

With that type of connection, the columns(fields) then become `F1`, `F2`, etc., where `F1` = column A, `F2` = column B, etc.

This is not ideal, since you are now essentially running the query based on the number of the column rather than the name, but with duplicate column names, this is the only way around that.

Per the comment from @barrowc: This format of the connection string will treat your column names as data.  So depending on your query, you may need to include code to filter out the row that contains your column names.

Comment: Thanks, that should be enough :)

Comment: This will cause the values in row 1 of the worksheet to be treated as data which may or may not be an issue depending on how you use the data