# How to select a column of specific letter in OleDB?

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledb

Actually, I'm trying to build a program that imports data to MySQL from Excel
but before it, the user will be able to choose the column which he would import to MySQL like column A, B or F, G, D

Actually, I was trying to use the following query where {0} should be 1st sheet and A the column I would select but I'm getting Object doesn't exist error

Here is the query

```
 Dim sqlquery As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}A]", myTableName)
```

**EDIT:**

If I specify the range like `SELECT * FROM [{0}A1:A111]` all works fine but the issue is that I can't know how much rows have the column A.

Comment: I think your answer is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360306/ado-how-to-select-column-from-xls-file-where-two-or-more-columns-have-the-same

Comment: @Mary actually i've yet tryed it and that wasn't working but actually i've noticed that the issue was HDR value, by setting it to NO all works, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
F1 is the first column.

```
Dim sqlquery As String = String.Format("SELECT F1 FROM [{0}]", myTableName)
```

Got the inspiration from here:
[Retrieving values of the first column from Excel sheet (file with .xlsm extension) with OleDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971054/retrieving-values-of-the-first-column-from-excel-sheet-file-with-xlsm-extensio)

Comment: Actually i've yet tryed it but i'm getting the following error when i try to use F1/F2 etc. "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Comment: My mistake actually i was no giving importance to HDR value by setting it to "NO" that works. Thank you